# Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: dijkstras-algorithm

I have couple of questions about Dijkstra algorithm

1. Can  the algorithm work if there are negative weights at the starting point?
2. Can we make the algorithm work with negative weights if we add a long long integer at all weights of edges so all the weights will be positive  integer?

Comment: What have you tried by yourself? Share the idea/effort you made.

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is directed and  there is no cycle involving the source then the answer for the first question is positive, and Dijkstra's algorithm work. Note that  negative edges only leaves the source.

For the second question, the answer is negative and Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't work. Because there is counter example.